# The difference in the meaning bristle and stubble

Tags: meaning

Talking about short stiff hair. Do bristle and stubble mean the same? Is there any subtle difference? Dictionaries say roughly the same thing and yet they're not synonyms

Comment: Stubble is what you're left with a day or two after shaving; only applicable to human faces (and possibly chests and legs in these days of full-body shaving). Bristles are stiffer, more rigid, and more unruly. They can be on your head, and they can be on other animals (and even plants).

Answer (score 2):

*Stubble* is a mass noun, originally referring to what is left in a  field after harvest, but often applied to skin shaved but not shaved smooth.

*Bristle* is a count noun, originally meaning a short stiff hair. It is not common in describing human facial hair, but it might be.

Comment: I will just add some examples with these words  for you to make it more clear.                                                                                  The young crop was hoed, reaping was performed with a sickle, and a high stubble left on the ground as manure.

Comment: As I explained, that is the original meaning of "stubble". It would be very strange to use "bristle(s)" to refer to stalks of plants.